# Spring-Batch: Testing Step Scoped Step

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to test the Spring Batch steps. I have 2 scenarios to test
1. Step with tasklet (step scoped)
2. Step with ItemReader/ItemWriter (step scope)

My test class is annotated as follows

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class})
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class, classes = ItemReturnsApplication.class)

This is how my test class looks like

@Bean
    JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils(){
        return new JobLauncherTestUtils();
    }

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

@Test
    public void testLaunchJob() throws Exception{
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(
                new JobParametersBuilder().addString("chunkSize", "3").addString("current_date","2016-11-25").toJobParameters()
        );
        commonAssertions(jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob());
        assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getStatus());
    }
```

When I run the test case, the process fails because the the job parameters are not getting passed into my job.

I am looking for the right way of testing the Step Scoped steps in spring batch.

Thanks,
Opensource Explorer

Answer (score 1):

Your current code attempts to launch and test **a job and not a step**. According to the spring batch [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/testing.html#testingIndividualSteps) on how to test individual steps, a simple example of how to test a tasklet and inject context into the tasklet is more in line with the following code:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners( { DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class StepScopeTestExecutionListenerIntegrationTests {

    // This component is defined step-scoped, so it cannot be injected unless
    // a step is active...
    @Autowired
    private YourTaskletClass yourTaskletClass;

    public StepExecution getStepExection() {
        StepExecution execution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution();
        execution.getExecutionContext().putString("input.data", "foo,bar,spam");
        return execution;
    }

    @Test
    public void testYourTaskletClass() {
        // The tasklet is initialized and some configuration is already set by the MetaDatAInstanceFactory           
        assertNotNull(yourTaskletClass.doSomething());
    }

}
```

The `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` annotation is only possible with a spring boot version of 1.4 and higher. For more information see [this](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4) blog.

To launch an individual step try adjusting your code to:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class})
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class, classes = ItemReturnsApplication.class)    
public class StepIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void testLaunchJob() throws Exception{
       JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("nameOfYourStep");

    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Sander, I updated my spring-boot to 1.4.1 and adjusted the Test case as suggested by you. I tried to execute a step which does not require Job Parameters, the observation is, the entire job starts and looks for Job Parameters and fails at the point where the job looks for Job Parameters.... Is this the expected behavior....